# Is it possible to add sources of Allegro library to Code::Blocks project?

Tags: c, project, codeblocks, allegro

I am making a game based on Allegro 4.4.2 library and I want its project to be as versatile as possible, so that I can just copy it, open in Code::Blocks (despite the platform), build and run.

My question is, is it possible to add sources of the Allegro library to my project instead of linking their compiled version to compiler? That way seems to be problematic if I would like to run it on platform other than mine, since I would need other binaries for the same library.

I tried just to add sources and headers of allegro and hit Build and Run. After compiling most of the files process terminated at allegro.c with a lot of "undefined reference to" errors, '_system_driver_list' being the first of them.

After some general searching I lighted upon something like adding library project, but nothing concerning Allegro.

Just to clarify - this is supposed to be school project, so besides versatility it would be great if I could show the code of the library I am basing my own on.

Thanks for all advices

Comment: You can add source files instead of linking object files if you have total source in hand.

Comment: Firstly I downloaded source and compiled it with CMake. Are those sources the total sources you mentioned? So the reason of my problem is that I did not add some important files from source to my project? If so, what should I add except /include and /src folders from source?